# Vue duplicate numbers in array breaks doom element

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Very weird situation, when I push any number which already exists in my array it duplicates and breaks my doom element. Array keeps normal, but doom displays something like this:

[image]

array: [image]

my watcher :

```
  lastWins(){
      console.log(this.lastWins);
      this.lastWins.shift();
   }
```

Doom:

```
<ul class="gameHistoryList_rou">
        <li :style="{background: historyCheckColor(win)}" v-for="win of lastWins" :key="win">{{ win }}</li>
      </ul>
```

method to push(splice for watch):

```
this.lastWins.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 36));
this.lastWins = this.lastWins.splice(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an unique `key` for each item.

Try this:

```
<ul class="gameHistoryList_rou">
    <li :style="{background: historyCheckColor(win)}" v-for="(win, index) of lastWins" :key="index">{{ win }}</li>
</ul>
```